# Loading multiple Vimeo videos into SharePoint 2013 pages, causes issues in Safari browsers

Tags: jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using the following code (in a .js file), to load multiple videos onto a publishing page in SharePoint 2013...

```
function vimeo() {

var mtarget = $('.vimeo.training');
if (mtarget.length) {

$.getJSON('//www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent('//vimeo.com/mvideo01?color=ffcd00&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0') + '&width=640&callback=?', function(data){
        mtarget.prepend(data.html);
});

$.getJSON('//www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent('//vimeo.com/mvideo02?color=ffcd00&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0') + '&width=640&callback=?', function(data){
        mtarget.prepend(data.html);
});

$.getJSON('//www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent('//vimeo.com/mvideo03?color=ffcd00&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0') + '&width=640&callback=?', function(data){
        mtarget.prepend(data.html);
});



}
//*/
}


$(window).load(function() {
vimeo();
});
```

In IE, Chrome, and FireFox, all the videos load/stack fine...but on an ipad - Safari browser, the iframes break and you can only see the first video. Is this a Vimeo issue for Safari browsers?

Thanks for any advice!

**UPDATE**

Thank you Ryan for helping me realize that SharePoint 2013 **site pages** handle rendering multiple Vimeo videos a lot better than SharePoint **publishing** pages do, especially if you care about Safari.

So the issue is not Vimeo, it's what type of pages you make in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a quick test page, used your code, and everything seems to be working fine for me.

http://labs.ryanhefner.com/tests/ipad-oembed/

I'm not sure if you are just using these as an example, but all I did was change the 'mvideo01', 'mvideo02', and 'mvideo03' to a valid `clip_id` (ex. 2) and everything seems to render fine for me, on an iPad 2.

Let me know if you continue to run into issues after change the mvideo0X.

Comment: Thank you Ryan for the testing and feedback!  Your response led me to do further testing in my SharePoint 2013 environment.  For one reason or another, the stacking of Vimeo videos works a lot better for Apple Mobile devices, when I create site pages. My original issue was with stacking iframe videos on publishing pages.  So I found my answer on how to move forward, but couldn't of done it without your feedback.  Thank you!